# Connecting to server with Knex, how to troubleshoot Error Unhandled rejection error: password authentication failed

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, server, knex.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const cors = require("cors");
const knex = require("knex");

const app = express();
const saltRounds = 10;
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const db = knex({
  client: "pg",
  version: "7.2",
  connection: {
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    // port: "5433",
    user: "postgres",
    password: "",
    database: "smart-brain"
  }
});

// Alternative
// const db = knex({
//   client: "pg",
//   connection: "postgres://postgres:@localhost:5433/smart-brain"
// });


// ERROR!!!
console.log(
  db
    .select("bob")
    .from("users")
    .then(data => console.log(data))
);
```

Error:
Unhandled rejection error: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Description: 
I am trying to connect my server to a database i have running. I actually follow along a video of the Complete 2020 Web Development Bootcamp. The big problem is it gives back the same error message every time, and the information i send in the request is seemingly correct.

Answer (score 0):

Okay figured it out, i did set a server password a long time ago but it was filled out automatically, and pgadmin was only asking for my master password on login. I know it's not ideal but it's fine if only i have access to everything.

The server was also having an issue of not liking the "requires" all the sudden, which added to the confusion, but it's fixed now.